# Trying to retrieve SPAN tags within nested DIV tags using JSOUP

Tags: xml-parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

Hello I am trying to extract the span tags that are in nested DIV tags, using JSoup.  The code below is just a snippet of larger code.

```html
<div class="formitem formgroup horizontal">
  <div class="formitem formgroup horizontal">
    <div class="formitem formgroup vertical" style="width:325px">
      <div class="formitem formgroup horizontal">
        <div class="formitem formgroup vertical" style="width:325px;">
          <div class="formitem formgroup horizontal">
            <span class="formitem formfield">
                            <span class="value" style="font-weight:bold">47 Lower River St</span>
            </span>
            <span class="formitem formfield">
                            <span class="value" style="font-weight:bold">531</span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formitem formgroup horizontal">
        <span class="formitem formfield">
                    <span class="value" style="font-weight:bold">Toronto</span>
        </span>
        <span class="formliteral formitem" />
        <span class="formitem formfield">
                    <span class="value">Ontario</span>
        </span>
        <span class="formliteral formitem" />
        <span class="formitem formfield">
                    <span class="value">M5A0G1</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formitem formgroup vertical" style="width:150px;">
      <div class="formitem formgroup horizontal">
        <span class="formitem formfield">
                    <label>List:</label>
                    <span class="value" style="font-weight:bold">$279,900</span>
        </span>
        <span class="formitem formfield">
                    <label>For:</label>
                    <span class="value" style="font-weight:bold">Sale</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="formitem formfield">
        <span class="value">Toronto C08</span>
  </span>
  <span class="formliteral formitem" />
  <span class="formitem formfield">
        <span class="value">Moss Park</span>
  </span>
  <span class="formliteral formitem" />
  <span class="formitem formfield">
        <span class="value">Toronto</span>
  </span>
  <span class="formitem formfield">
        <span class="value">120-21-S</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the text in the last SPAN tags (Toronto C08, Moss Park, Toronto and  120-21-S)

```html
<span class="formitem formfield">
    <span class="value">Toronto C08</span>
</span>
<span class="formliteral formitem" />
<span class="formitem formfield">
    <span class="value">Moss Park</span>
</span>
<span class="formliteral formitem" />
<span class="formitem formfield">
    <span class="value">Toronto</span>
</span>
<span class="formitem formfield">
    <span class="value">120-21-S</span>
</span>
```

I have parsed other parts of the document with success however, I can't seem to isolate these spans.  The snippet of code is from a much larger page ([full page](http://v3.torontomls.net/Live/Pages/Public/Link.aspx?Key=4fb27e624b1c4e8c8cd9543a3eef1a3e&App=TREB%22)).  I may be using the wrong approach, but here is what I did to capture the spans between the parent DIV (results at top of post).

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div[class=formitem legacyBorder formgroup vertical]");
        Element zoneElement = elements.select("div[class=formitem formgroup vertical")
                 .select("[style=width:500px]").select("div[class=formitem formgroup horizontal").first();
```

So now I have the first element but I need the last 6 span tags at the end of the block of selected code.  Thanks

Comment: why u need spoonfeeding

Comment: If it's just a snippet of a larger code, the actual selector may be different from the selector for the snippet. Can you post the link of the web page?

Comment: Here is link to the full page: [link](http://v3.torontomls.net/Live/Pages/Public/Link.aspx?Key=4fb27e624b1c4e8c8cd9543a3eef1a3e&App=TREB).  I also added a some more information to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your browser's `developer tool` (F12), select the "inspect elements" tool, highlight the field you want (e.g. TORONTO C08) and choose its `css selector`. For "TORONTO C08" it will be:

```
#C3627690 > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)
```

Do the same for all the other elemens. After getting all the selectors, check them closely - maybe they have a common pattern (e.g different only at the 3rd value), so you will be able to iterate over them with a loop.

Comment: Thanks TDG, I was hoping there may be a simpler way, but looking at examples, this may be the most direct way.  I have looked a lot of listings. The pattern is with the last span tags (always 6). Other listings have thrown in an extra div tag so the CSS select could break.  Also the ID's are unique. I have code that will extract id's.  I was looking at JSoup's pseudo selector **bold** ':nth-last-child(an+b)'  Looking at this, I think I can select from the bottom up. I will try this in combination with your solution and let you know if I come up with a solution. Unless you see something better?

Comment: TDG solution works so marked it as a solutions.  There a many ways to skin a cat so I came up with this solution:

Comment: 'int zoneSize = elements.select("div[class=formitem formgroup vertical]").select("[style=width:500px]").select("div[class=formitem formgroup horizontal").first().select("span[class=formitem formfield").select("span[class=value]").size();
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
String zone = elements.select("div[class=formitem formgroup vertical]").select("[style=width:500px]").select("div[class=formitem formgroup horizontal").first().select("span[class=formitem formfield").select("span[class=value]").get(zoneSize - i).text();
System.out.println(zone);
}'

Comment: Glad that it works for you. You can also post your solution as an answer - as you said - there are many ways to skin a cat...